# React Native Conditionally render elements basic on prop been undefined or value provided

Tags: reactjs

Looking for a cleaner way to render and change icon size basic on if my size prop is undefined or if a value is provided

example if props.size is undefined the size should be 30 however if props.size is equal to 20 then the icon will have a size of 20

works

```
<TheIcon name={props.iconName} size={props.size ? props.size : 30} />
```

Would the below code work or do the same. I am looking for a cleaner way to do the code above

```
<TheIcon name={props.iconName} size={props.size ?? 30} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this if props.size == undefined then harder coded value 30 else use the size.

```
<TheIcon name={props.iconName} size={props.size == undefined ? 30 : props.size} />
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is a nullish operator and does not at all behave as the ternary operator.

For more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator